# no output file generated when using Ghostscript to convert PDF to TIFF

Tags: pdf, tiff, ghostscript

Here is the command I use:

```
gs -r300 -q -dNOPAUSE -sDevice=tiffgray -sOutputFile=sample1.tiff sample1.pdf -c quit
```

I don't see sample1.tiff in my current working directory. I'm running OS Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

Try running without -q so that the messages aren't suppressed, Ghostscript is probably trying to tell you what's wrong.